# PostgreSQL checking for empty array changes behavior in Golang

Tags: sql, postgresql, go

I'm trying to implement the behavior of selecting data based on either an array of input, *or get all data* if array is null or empty.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
    WHERE 
        ('{}' = $1 OR col = ANY($1))
```

This will return `pq: op ANY/ALL (array) requires array on right side`.

If I run

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
    WHERE 
        (col = ANY($1))
```

This works just fine and I get the contents I expected.

I can also use `array_length` but it will request me to assert what type of data is in $1. If I do `(array_length($1::string[],1) < 1 OR col = ANY($1))`, it seems to always return false on the array_length and go on to the `col = ANY($1)`

How can I return either JUST the values from $1 OR all if $1 is `'{}'` or NULL?

Answer (score -1):

Got it:

`($1::string[] IS NULL OR event_id = ANY($1))`

Comment: Can you update this answer to be helpful for other users with the same or similar issue? e.g. explain *why* this change fixes the issue beyond just "got it"?